# How do I capture multiple characters with (\s|\S) (i.e. p OR not p)?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse an email that is being passed to the function looking like this:

```
From: Bob  
Sent: Thursday  
To: Jack  
Cc: Mary, Zaphod,  
Janice, Trillian  
Subject: Restaurant at the End of the Universe

I can't seem to find this on the map, any help?  
Is it on I-95?
```

The regex I'm using looks like this:

```
From:(?:\s){0,}(.*)(?:\s){1,}Sent:(.*)(?:\s){1,}To:(.*)(?:\s){1,}Cc:(\s|\S){1,}(?:\s){1,}Subject:(.*)(\s){1,}(.*)
```

The issue is this only captures the last char of the Cc information and a single line of the body of the email.

I could use the `DOTALL` flag and change the (\s|\S){1,} after Cc and Subject to (.*):

```
From:(?:\s){0,}(.*)(?:\s){1,}Sent:(.*)(?:\s){1,}To:(.*)(?:\s){1,}Cc:(.*){1,}(?:\s){1,}Subject:(.*)(\s){1}(.*)
```

But this merges the body and the subject.

Is there any way to capture more than one char with p or not p, or should I just use the `DOTALL` split the subject and body in a separate way?

Comment: Don't use a regex, use a by line approach with `startswith` and `split`, it's more efficient.

Comment: Python has [an `email.parser` module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/email.parser.html) for exactly this.  Why not use it?

Comment: You could do that without using regex. `s.split('Cc:')[1].split('Subject:')[0]` returns `' Mary, Zaphod,\nJanice, Trillian\n'`.

Comment: Looks like [`email.parser` does not work here](http://ideone.com/rmEQYi) (or maybe it's just me :)). Are there more than 1 block you need to obtain from the text? Try [`From:\s*(.*)\s+Sent:\s*(.*)\s+To:\s*(.*)\s+Cc:([\s\S]*?)\s+Subject:(.*)(?:\s+([\s\S]*))?`](https://regex101.com/r/gH3tC2/1)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I could, but I don't want it to split a massive email chain every time someone says "from", "sent","to", or "subject". It seems like a bad assumption that the program will never see these in the body. I would need "from:*sent:*to:*", and I believe the best way to do that is to use regex, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Since the header is separated from the body and "from: ", "cc: ", ... are always at the start of a line there is no risk.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I see what you're saying. I'm trying to parse an email chain, so that isn't going to work, unfortunately, which is why I opted for regex. I did try that route initially.

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-greedy match to match everything until `Subject`:

```
From:(?:\s){0,}(.*)(?:\s){1,}Sent:(.*)(?:\s){1,}To:(.*)(?:\s){1,}Cc:([\s\S]*?)Subject:(.*)(\s){1,}([\s\S]*)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sQ5nN0/1)

To match the same pattern multiple times, you can use look ahead to make sure the next section starts with `From:` or is the end:

```
From:(?:\s){0,}(.*)(?:\s){1,}Sent:(.*)(?:\s){1,}To:(.*)(?:\s){1,}Cc:([\s\S]*?)Subject:(.*)(\s){1,}([\s\S]*?)(?=(From:|$))
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sQ5nN0/2)

I think this is getting complicated enough that it's time to use a more robust solution like an email parser.

Comment: That is a wicked resource, I was using a different debugger, but I like the explanation on the right. The other thing I noticed was that this only matches the first email. If I have a chain, ie a number of replies, is there a way to have this repeat a number of times? I tried to use grouping, but obviously I am not very experienced with regular expressions.

Comment: @JFA. you could use regex's lookahead feature. see updated answer.

Comment: I'm looking at parser right now. My google-fu must be weak today because I found email.utils but not email.parser. Honestly if I could not write this all out by hand and reinvent the wheel, it would be fantastic.

Comment: @JFA, I did a little digging too. looks like email chains are not standardized. so unfortunately, there isn't a straightforward solution. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168719/parsing-forwarded-emails.

Comment: that's one of the issues I'm facing, in one of our test emails, someone's client quoted the previous messages as saying "On (date) JFA wrote:" and that's it :/

Comment: I have a followup question if it's not too much trouble, how would I additionally capture the entire email as a whole? I tried wrapping it in parenthesis, but no dice.

Comment: The entire match is captured as group zero (`group(0)` or just `group()`).

Comment: @Fabricator I wound up using it in a different way

Answer (score 1):

You could probably generalize it a bit more and do some trimming all at once.
I added named groups, but you could remove them, or change to the `(?P<>)` Python form.

```
From:\s*\s*(?<From>.*?)\s+Sent:\s*(?<Sent>.*?)\s+To:\s*(?<To>[\S\s]*?)\s+Cc:\s*(?<Cc>[\S\s]*?)\s+Subject:\s*(?<Subject>.*?)\s*(?=\r?\n|$)(?:\r?\n(?<Message>[\S\s]+?\S[\S\s]+?)\s*$)?
```

Blowup

```
 From: \s* 
 \s* 
 (?<From> .*? )                # (1), From: single line
 \s+ 
 Sent:
 \s* 
 (?<Sent> .*? )                # (2), Sent: single line
 \s+ 
 To:
 \s* 
 (?<To> [\S\s]*? )             # (3), To: multiple line's possible
 \s+ 
 Cc:
 \s* 
 (?<Cc> [\S\s]*? )             # (4), Cc: multiple line's possible
 \s+ 
 Subject:
 \s* 
 (?<Subject> .*? )             # (5), Subject: single line
 \s* 
 (?= \r? \n | $ )
 (?:                           # Optional message body
      \r? \n 
      (?<Message>                   # (6 start), Message: multiple line's possible
           [\S\s]+? 
           \S 
           [\S\s]+? 
      )                             # (6 end)
      \s* 
      $    
 )?
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 1 [From]    -  ( pos 6 , len 3 ) 
Bob  
 **  Grp 2 [Sent]    -  ( pos 19 , len 8 ) 
Thursday  
 **  Grp 3 [To]      -  ( pos 35 , len 4 ) 
Jack  
 **  Grp 4 [Cc]      -  ( pos 47 , len 33 ) 
Mary, Zaphod,  
Janice, Trillian  
 **  Grp 5 [Subject] -  ( pos 93 , len 37 ) 
Restaurant at the End of the Universe  
 **  Grp 6 [Message] -  ( pos 134 , len 65 ) 
I can't seem to find this on the map, any help?  
Is it on I-95?
```